How to work with UART to make communication between stm32 and hmi nextion display in noisy environment?
in an ultrasonic generator project, I am using an STM32F334 microcontroller as the main controller and an HMI Nextion display (model NX8048T070) that includes another STM32 for driving the monitor. I utilize UART to send live data from the STM32F334 to the display, showing parameters such as elapsed time, frequency, and more. However, when the inverter operates, significant noise interferes, causing the display to fail in showing the numbers. so how should I work with UART in noisy environment?
I tried different types of monitors. like tft ili9488 that its communication protocol is based on spi. some technical people said spi gets noise easier so I changed the type of monitor. then I tried nextion hmi monitor with UART protocol. but problem didnt solved. I tried to make distance between transformers and the display and this also didnt work

Hello and welcome.  Could you tell us about what kind of line driver you're using, if any, and the distance and the data rate.  It may be that something like RS-485 and slower rates will help.  Or of course optical, if that's viable.
